# Am I taking a course "on" or "at" an educational website?

Tags: prepositions

I recently wrote a blog post and found it incredibly difficult to decide whether to state that I am taking a course "on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org)" as one might say if Facebook, for instance, started offering courses, or - as one would say of a University course - "at Coursera". What is the correct usage?

Comment: Someone else might be able to answer with references, but in my experience if you are going to a location you use "at" and if you are on the computer you say "on"

Comment: Using the verb "take" you have to use the particle "on", albeit - in cases like this - "at" is in common usage.

Comment: @carlo no. You can "take a course at college" just as correctly as you can "take a course on math"

Comment: Related questions: ["On website" or "at website"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/on-website-or-at-website) and
["This question has been asked at Stack Overflow" vs. "on Stack Overflow"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/this-question-has-been-asked-at-stack-overflow-vs-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*With Coursera* might get round the problem.

Comment: Does this apply to all dialects? Sounds distinctly American to me, for some reason.

Comment: I think *with* is syntactically/semantically equivalent to *at* here. The only problem is that *on* admits of the (rather unlikely, imho) interpretation that OP is studying Coursera itself, rather than following a course offered by that website.

Comment: @okal As a British English native speaker, 'Taking a course with Coursera' sounds fine to me. 'Taking a course with my local college' would sound a little more strained, however.

Comment: Get round the problem... or exacerbate the problem! (Now there are _three_ prepositions to choose from.)  Then again, "I'm taking a course _through_ Coursera" might work, too.

Comment: FWIW, I woke up this morning and thought of yet another way to say this: "I'm taking a course offered _by_ Coursera."

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure whether there is any one 'correct' answer. In this example, 'At' suggests to me physical presence for a certain purpose e.g. 'I was waiting at the bus stop', 'I'll meet you at the restaurant'. One would probably not say 'There was a dog at the restaurant' because dogs do not go to restaurants to eat; '...in the restaurant' would be better.

You probably want to say 'on (the website)' because of the lack of physical presence at the online college.

I fear that 'at' is dying out. Brit speakers are saying 'On the weekend' these days, following the Am Eng practice. When I was a boy, *everyone* said 'At the weekend'.

Comment: I agree with everything except the comment in the last paragraph--I'm not sure it helps answer the question.

Comment: @simchona I'm Kenyan. We speak a variant of British English, so the last comment does add value.

Comment: @okal it's a different usage of at/on, though, relating to time instead of place. It's a useful comment for a different question.

Comment: Ah! Good point. Hadn't thought of it that way.

Comment: What simchona said. Relative prevalence of [on at / over / for the weekend](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+weekend%2Cat+the+weekend%2Cover+the+weekend%2Cfor+the+weekend&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) isn't relevant. And I'm not aware that British usage is following American there anyway - most Brits I know say *"**at** the weekend"*, same as ever.

Comment: But *I am taking a course **on** east campus*, eh?