# "publish in" vs. "publish on"

Tags: prepositions

I've been searching thoroughly for both constructions, but I haven't been able to find out when to use each of them.

Some rules of thumb I've found:

> - [This forum post](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/forum/showthread.php?52-Prepositions-publish-to-in-on-a-blog&s=2e9ffa3c2e1f237f8703c2f46acef517&p=304#post304) and [this one](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1406044&p=7122407#post7122407) suggest *publish in* should be used when the place of publishing is a three-dimensional place and *publish on* should be used when it's a surface. This makes a bit of sense to me, but does not seem a very academical explanation; whereas there are some cases in which it would be hard to distinguish which kind of place it is.

- When the place is virtual, *on* is used. Example: [Publish on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/index.html)

My particular cases are the following:

> - To publish an application __ [in/on] Google Play

- To publish an application __ [in/on] a virtual market

Is there a way to identify where to use *publish in* or *publish on*? Are they mutually exchangeable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Am I taking a course "on" or "at" an educational website?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73204/am-i-taking-a-course-on-or-at-an-educational-website)

Comment: If you have to convince an editor or reviewer to *let you in* metaphorically, it’s probably makes sense to use *in*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Google Play and the iTunes Store are virtual locations, so I would follow the normal usage for other such locations (i.e., the Web), and prefer *on* in most cases.

One exception would be if something were being published *in* a recognized journal that has both a physical and a virtual presence: I would refer to "an article in *The New York Times*" for example, whether it's being read online or in newsprint. The same goes for *JAMA* (Journal of the American Medical Association), and even the *Oxford English Dictionary*.

Comment: Huh?  I don't think I've ever heard of publishing an app on the Play store.  I seems to always be in the play store.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, the difference between *in* and *on* boils down to which [Dimensional Metaphor](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/71574/15299) the speaker (or writer) is applying.

From the [*Deixis Lectures*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf):

> ".. the preposition *on* is said to ascribe to the referent of its head noun the property of being a line or a surface, and the preposition *in* is said to ascribe to the referent of its head noun the notion of a bounded two-dimensional or three-dimensional space."

We daily encounter and use dimensional metaphors with *on* and *in* for things that are not physical.

- 2-Dimensional: *on the page, on the table, on vacation, on top of the problem, on Sunday*
- 3-Dimensional: *in trouble, in on the secret, in the novel, in the time alotted, in March*

That's the difference between *lawn* and *yard*, for instance.

- A *lawn* is a two-dimensional space, so a human being can be *on the lawn*; but understanding a report that someone is *in the lawn* requires some unusual assumptions.
- A *yard* is a bounded two-dimensional space, and its bounding makes it three-dimensional with regard to human presence. Thus one is *in the yard*, and saying *on the yard* invites a mental search for a different meaning of *yard*.

Executive summary:

> 1. If you think of Google Play as a container full of stuff, use *in*.
> 2. If you think of it as a page on a screen, use *on*.

Comment: That's what I got from the 2 first links I gave in the question. However, Google itself uses _on_ to talk about _to publish on_ Google Play. Being Google Play a _service_, not only a _virtual market_ as it was _Android Market_ in the past. Therefore, I'm starting to believe the _virtual/physical_ dichotomoy applies better.

Comment: It's not in contrast; at the metaphorical level, people don't think logically. After all, metaphor starts off by violating the Law of Contradiction, which is the first premise of logic. And different people use different metaphors; nothing is universal except individuality.

Comment: You're certainly right about metaphors... I truly believe that's the origin of the problem when trying to place the right preposition

Answer (score 0):

You are published in a magazine. but published on the web or on paper.

`On` is if you are referring to media, and `In` is if you are to the medium.

Answer (score 0):

'Published in our (online) catalog' sounds fine to me, as 'in' is the right preposition for the word 'catalog' which is a published physical format. For example, you wouldn't say 'Published on our online magazine.' That just sounds awkward. I prefer 'in' for references to specific physical publication formats even if they are actually on the internet, i.e magazine, catalog, guide, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> When the place is virtual, on is used. Example: Publish on Google Play

This has now been changed to "with".

**In = inside; within** - this gives the idea of the item being inside/within boundaries.

**On = upon** - this gives the idea of the item being on a surface of some sort.

Publish **on** Google Play is correct because "Google Play" is seen as a (virtual) **platform**. A platform is a surface.