# Do I play a game "in" hard mode or "on" hard mode?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to use a contracted form of "play a game with the difficulty set to hard".

Which of these options would be more appropriate?:

> - Play a game **in** hard mode
> - Play a game **on** hard mode

Maybe this is similar to cooking pasta "alla bolognese", or cooking pasta in a bolognese manner.

Comment: I think the standard idiom is "in", because your character (and by extension, you) are "in" the game.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211543/what-is-correct-playing-on-a-squash-court-or-in-a-squash-court

Comment: @tchrist, I can't see why this is off-topic. Why is this not off-topic: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94584/publish-in-vs-publish-on?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 6):

It's "on" because it is used in conjunction with the difficulty setting. It doesn't matter if YOU're playing the game; what matters is the setting it is on.

I'm not playing on easy. I'm playing on hard.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen both, and a Google search, while not rock-solid "evidence", at least gives us an indication that both are more-or-less equally popular.

> "completed in hard mode" -> 3,120 results
>   "completed on hard mode" -> 3,560 results

So, "on" is more popular, but only by 14%.

I'd say it's a matter of preference, or perhaps style.

Comment: What's most popular doesn't always translate to what's more correct... especially with a video gaming audience

Comment: @Othya I completely agree (hence my disclaimer about evidence)', but I'm not sure if either of them is really "correct" anyway: it depends what metaphor you choose to describe games and their difficulty.  It may be more a matter of convention than correctness.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answers from Max Williams & Jasper Locke I continue to make the case for **on**.

Even though generally the preposition **in** is more common with *mode* than **on**. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+*+mode%2C+on+*+mode&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cin%20%2A%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20the%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20their%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20this%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20a%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20his%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20its%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20that%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20any%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20some%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20every%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Con%20%2A%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20this%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20a%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20their%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20his%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20its%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20that%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20every%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20some%20mode%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20our%20mode%3B%2Cc0)

Also more specifically "*in **adjective** mode*" results in tens of thousands of hits on [Google Books Corpora](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=49437221) while "*on **adjective** mode*" results in [162 total](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=49437137).

If searching for *play on/in hard mode* the difference is bigger than in Max' search:

[33k on](https://www.google.de/search?as_q=&as_epq=play+on+hard+mode&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) vs [12k in](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22play+in+hard+mode%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=QFCkV_WvIcGo8wfFt6vADw)

It's not uniform through other difficulty settings though:

- play on/in easy mode (20k on vs 9k in)
- play on/in normal mode (17k on vs 40k in)
- play on/in beginner mode (2.7k on vs "did you mean "play on beginner mode")

In a nutshell, generally **in** is used in conjunction with **mode** and gamers can't seem to decide which one to use. It even varies between difficulty modes.

---

Yet you also ask, **Is there a proper way to say that in a more direct fashion?**

I would simply suggest to use difficulty (level) instead of mode. Indicators from google searches ([275k](https://www.google.de/search?as_q=&as_epq=play+on+hard+mode&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&q=%22on+hard+difficulty%22) to [35k](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22play+in+hard+mode%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=QFCkV_WvIcGo8wfFt6vADw#q=%22in+hard+difficulty%22) in favor of **on**) to the random sample I did of steam achievement texts (Beat the game on any difficulty level, Overthrow the aliens on Legend difficulty) seem to suggest on is more popular.

Furthermore **on** works nicely for all extensions or shortenings of the usual sentences and can be used well with both difficulty and mode:

- Play on hard (Even excluding *mode* or *difficulty* the results are almost purely gaming related, for play in hard, gaming takes a clear backseat)
- Play on hard mode
- Play on hard difficulty
- Play on hard difficulty level

Comment: Wow. The grammatical answer is clearly "**in**", yet your research shows "**on**" is winning. I'm shocked.