# "book available at" or "book available on?"

Tags: grammar, phrases

What's the correct way of saying it?

"X book is available at Amazon" or "X book is available on Amazon?"

Comment: possible duplicate of ["This question has been asked at Stack Overflow" vs. "on Stack Overflow"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/this-question-has-been-asked-at-stack-overflow-vs-on-stack-overflow) which is linked from ["On website" or "at website"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/on-website-or-at-website)

Answer (score 3):

" ... is available on ..." usually refers to websites only.

" ... is available at ..." usually refers to something being available at a particular physical location e.g "The book is available at Waterstones in Delhi."

" .. is available from ...." would be a better phrase to use as it covers both physical real locations and websites.

Assuming X is the title of the book, you could say

"X is available from Amazon and all good quality bookshops in your area".

or

"The book, X, is available from Amazon and all independent bookshops in your area."

Comment: Thanks. I checked the other questions. It seems like "at" is also used when referring to the URL of a site.