# "at a URL" or "on a URL"?

Tags: prepositions

I have to write "you can find ... **on** http://www.blablabla.com". But I am unsure, if I should write "on" or "at". May anybody help me with that?

Comment: I'd generally use "at", but I don't think the P-ists have acknowledged the existence of the Internet yet.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Both forms are used; *on* if you think of the URL as a publication, *at* if a location. The previous questions *[“On website” or “at website”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8226)* and *[“This question has been asked at Stack Overflow” vs. “on Stack Overflow”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3491)* may be informative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links! Unfortunately, my question is a duplicate... I had actually searched for, but I should have replace 'URL' with 'website'...

Comment: @choster : I think of Web sites (and parts thereof) as publications, which are located at their respective URLs. So I'm currently responding to material on Stack Exchange, at `http://stackexchange.com`. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"At url" would be the idiomatic way to say this.

For these sorts of questions [google ngram is your friend.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20url%2Con%20url&year_start=1990&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20url%3B%2Cc0) There you see that the usage of "at" occurs and "on" does not.

One of the commenters is correct though, when you are talking about a web site by name rather than by url you can say either "at StackOverflow" or "on StackOverflow" but the latter is more common. Again, using "cnn.com" as an example, [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20cnn.com%2Cat%20cnn.com&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20cnn.com%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20cnn.com%3B%2Cc0) votes clearly for "on" but certainly allows for "at".