# Go to a website or go at a website

Tags: prepositions

I have an easy question about the correct usage of the prepositions after the verb "go" when we want to refer to a website.

Which of these is the more correct expression?

A) If you want to download that file, you have to go AT ThisIsATest.com

B) If you want to download that file, you have to go TO ThisIsATest.com

Is it true that the former sentence is used in American English and the latter is used in British English?

I've just found out on the Internet that some people use "go ON". Is this other alternative correct?

Comment: When you *go at* something, you're *attacking* it, *attempting* it ('have a go' at it), or otherwise doing something to it other than simply *visiting* it. I favour BrE (British English), but I don't think AmE speakers would say otherwise. Regarding the later edit, I'd still prefer *go to* or *visit* to *go on*. I don't think it is idiomatic to say "go on a website" in the sense you intend. You can, however, say that a *picture* or *blog* should *go on* (i.e. be *placed on* or *uploaded to*) the website.

Comment: I've encountered lots of instances of people saying "go on `<website name>` and do such and such`.  Like *"Go on facebook and tell everyone about it"* or *"go on google and look for blah"*.

Comment: In British English I would always use 'to'  - 'to download the file, go to [link]'.  'Go on' and 'Go at' do not have the same meaning, at least in British English.

Comment: To @MaxWilliams point, if you are talking about visiting a website you might say 'go on/onto' that website to download the file, but if you are writing an instruction or content linking to the web page, then I think 'go to [url]' would be better.

Comment: @rhm ah yes you are right - you might say *"Go onto facebook"*, but you would say *"go **to** facebook.com"*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["On website" or "at website"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/on-website-or-at-website)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think so, this question specifically includes the link to the web resource, not the web site name. Doesn't make it rocket science either though. ;)

Comment: @Helmar: I linked to that question because the title here *(Go to a website or go at a website)* is obviously "the same" question as *"On website" or "at website"*. But that itself is closed as a duplicate of [*“This question has been asked at Stack Overflow” vs. “on Stack Overflow”*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/), where the top-rated answer specifically says *The only time you might see "at" used is when describing the full URL for a website*. That's good enough for me, since we're *always* getting questions on this tiresome matter. *Correct?* Give me a break!

Answer (score 0):

Use **go to www.somelink.com**

There is no occurrence of **go on/at www**(.whatever.domain) in any book. Whilst there are nearly [28 thousand for **go to www**](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=49475357). This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+to+www%2Cgo+on+www%2C+go+at+www&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cgo%20to%20www%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgo%20to%20www%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGo%20to%20www%3B%2Cc0) also shows only one trend.

There is no variation in the searches between American English and British English.

Comment: @cobaltduck Thx, somehow the comments made me only include go on. I changed the link.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some definitions of *go* when used in different ways:

> **Go**
>
> *verb*
> 1.3 (go to) Attend or visit for a particular purpose: *we went to the cinema*
>
> *noun, informal*
> 1 *chiefly British* An attempt or trial at something: *have a go at answering the questions yourself*
>
> *noun, informal*
> 2 *British* A person’s turn to use or do something: *I had a go on Nigel’s racing bike*
>
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/go)

When you *go at* something, you're attacking it, attempting it (*have a go* at it), or otherwise doing something to it other than simply visiting it.

For the purpose of this discussion, we would consider a website to be a *place*, so you would direct people to *go to* the website.

It is also idiomatic to say, for example, "Go on Facebook". However, this carries the sense of logging onto the site or needing to go through some process of entering your credentials, rather than simply visiting it.

So to answer your specific questions:

- A or B: your sentence B ("go *to* ThisIsATest.com") would be preferred over sentence A ("go *at* ThisIsATest.com").
- BrE vs AmE: I usually favour British English, but I believe American English speakers would concur with this conclusion.
- *to* vs *on*: if you are directing people *to* a site, treating the site as the destination, use *go to* (or simply "visit ThisIsATest.com", leaving out *go* altogether). If you are including the notion of site access (passwords, etc), it could be argued that *go on* is in common use, but it would be better to say, "Go onto ThisIsATest.com", or better yet, "Log into ThisIsATest.com".