# ... 'can be found in' 'can be found on' ? (Prepositions)

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which is the correct way of saying,

the document can be found **in** www.example.com/ark

or

the document can be found **on** www.example.com/ark 
or

the document is located **at** www.example.com/ark

Comment: Related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/this-question-has-been-asked-at-stack-overflow-vs-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since URLs give the *location* of an internet resource,

"the document is located at www.example.com/ark"

is correct. If instead of the URL you were using the name of the website, eg. 'Ark', then you could say:

"the document is located on Ark"

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "at" is your best choice because it is "at" a particular location.