# "I saw the job ad at..." or "I saw the job ad in..."

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should I use when referring to the possibly abstract place where I saw a job ad? E.g.

> I am writing to apply for XYZ. I saw the job advertisement **at** LinkedIn. **OR** I saw the job advertisement **in** LinkedIn.

Comment: For a website such as LinkedIn, Facebook, Google, etc., I would use "on" (ie "on a webpage").  "I found the article **on** Google."  "I saw the job advertisement **on** LinkedIn." Here's a link that might help: https://strategiesforparents.com/in-the-website-or-on-the-website-using-the-right-preposition/

Comment: This older thread might answers this question, too: ["This question has been asked at Stack Overflow" vs. "on Stack Overflow"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/this-question-has-been-asked-at-stack-overflow-vs-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: The usual prepositions and their contexts are: _in_ a newspaper or magazine, _at_ a physical location such as a recruitment organisation's office, and _on_ a website or notice board. The reason for the last one is probably that, originally, websites were closest in feel and style to public noticeboards. They are also divided into "pages" and the preposition "on" is used for items located on specific pages, for example "I saw your advert _in_ the Clarion, _on_ page four."